# CIPerspectiveTransform's behaviour

Tags: ios, core-image, perspective, cifilter

I'm currently working on `CIPerspectiveTransform`, and I can't seem to find it's exact behaviour. At least I've got an idea but I'm not pretty sure of it. I'll expose what I found out here.

As we can see in the [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform), there are 4 attributes of type `CIVector` :

```
inputTopLeft
A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypePosition and whose display name is Top Left.
Default value: [118 484]

inputTopRight
A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypePosition and whose display name is Top Right.

Default value: [646 507]

inputBottomRight
A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypePosition and whose display name is Bottom Right.
Default value: [548 140]

inputBottomLeft
A CIVector object whose attribute type is CIAttributeTypePosition and whose display name is Bottom Left.
Default value: [155 153]
```

As you can see, the default values are quite arbitrary. But that gives an effect of perspective to the given image. However, that doesn't really help to know how that actually works. So I began picking arbitrary values for these `CIVector`. And after a few tries, I found out that this :

```
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:0 Y:200] forKey:@"inputTopLeft"];
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:200 Y:200] forKey:@"inputTopRight"];
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:0 Y:0] forKey:@"inputBottomLeft"];
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:200 Y:0] forKey:@"inputBottomRight"];
```

applied to my image would do nothing on it (my `UIImageView` is subview to a `UIScrollView`). So I changed the values to 600x600 and I saw that nothing changed, except for the size of the resulting image. 200x200 in the first case, and 600x600 then.

So here's my question : **Why does my image print a square 200x200 size whereas I'm working on an iPhone device and it is perfectly rectangular ?**

Comment: *note: your CIVector code should be in this format: `[CIVector vectorWithX:320 Y:80]`

Answer (score 1):

Those `CIVectors` describe desired position of the image corners after the perspective transformation. Since those vectors have only two dimensions (X, Y) you can think about them as if they were `CGPoints` of the new image corners.

In your example you would need to specify:

```
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:50 Y:200] forKey:@"inputTopLeft"];
[perspectiveFilter setValue:[CIVectorWithX:150 Y:200] forKey:@"inputTopRight"];
```

to get perspective similar to the Star Wars opening crawl.

Comment: Does not make any sense why the values of your answer will produce a star wars like effect? First you are just defining 2 points. Second, the points you are not defining, `inputBottomRight` and `inputBottomLeft` are defined by Apple with insane default values of [548 140] and [155 153], respectively. Third because how this combination of points of yours and apple's will give the effect on any given image or any size? Apple documentation is garbage, so, one has to try to contact the twilight zone to understand what they mean by their poorly written documentations. If you can help I appreciate.

Comment: When you have an image 200x200 then by moving the top left corner by 50px to the right and moving the top right corner 50px to the left you transform a square image: |__| to a projection where the top edge is shorter: /__\. In my answer I assumed the remaining two points have the original image position: (0, 0) and (200,0). Apple set default values to show perspective, but you need to overwrite each corner with your value. You specify coordinates of the new image so it will be a valid setting for any input image

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but for some reason, if I do what you say I end with an effect upside down  \\_/ and also the image inside the effect is upside down too. I am using images coming from AVFoundation camera. I discover in practice that these CIFilters are a fountain of bugs. Some filters, for example, generate infinite images that when combined with others produce blank images and so one. Their docs are awful and explains crap, like all their docs. Anyway, thanks for the explanation and get my upvote!

Comment: Keep in mind that unlike in UIKit where origin (0,0) is in the top-left corner, CoreImage has the origin in the bottom-left corner. Perhaps this is causing the confusion. I've been using CI for about 5 years and it's pretty stable, but you are right: documentation could be better so you always need to experiment a bit before getting something working.

Comment: ahh, I forgot that little detail that Apple changes origin to make it difficult! thanks!